# Unity client server is not connected while using sendbychannel

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-networking

while running the unity game engine as client and server in one machine, working perfectly fine just initially its giving error,

> NetworkClient SendByChannel when not connected to a server
>   UnityEngine.Networking.NetworkClient:SendByChannel(Int16, MessageBase, Int32)
>   playerController:Update()

Can anyone please tell me why this error is coming?

Here the client is sending his position and server renders the texture and sends it back to him. But when the client is running on the Android (mobile) and server on the desktop, every time I am getting

> NetworkClient SendByChannel when not connected to a server.

I can't set the connection between server and client.

Can anyone please tell me why the connection is not getting set up?

The channel ID is same and everything I checked (IP and port no about firewall). Nothing list above is a problem.

Comment: How exactly did you exclude problems with e.g. the firewall? It's also difficult to say anything without seeing your code...

Comment: What I am observing from Wireshark, my mobile generates some periodic query to the multicast DNS IP address (224.0.0.251). That's all I have seen from that IP. While on the same desktop, the client and server are working fine as I told you earlier. I also ran simple TCP server on desktop and client on phone. differently and it works also fine. Can you please give me any suggestions?

Comment: I can share my code with you to have your exact opinion and advice. But it's difficult to share in the comment section. Can you please tell me how can I share with you?